# In Highcharts, how to prevent legend pagination down arrow button get cut off?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

With Highcharts, while the legend box aligns at right of the chart, with lots of legend items, it provides a legend item pagination, and scroll up/down buttons. However, sometimes the scroll down button got cut off from the right edge of the window.

[image]

I found out it only happens when the legend items' texts are too short (1 letter), which causes the width of the legend box to be not wide enough to cover the whole pagination button set.

I don't know why Highcharts doesn't take the width of the pagination button set as a parameter while calculating the legend box width. I believe this is an issue that Highcharts needs to solve.

Anyway, is there a nice way to solve this problem? I couldn't find any properties in `legend` to make it work.

Here is a fiddle of this issue, not as terrible as the image, but still makes a point.
https://jsfiddle.net/scottszb1987/aquurLfc/

Comment: You can increase [spacingRight parameter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.spacingRight) Which browser do you use? I run your demo in the newest Chrome and was not able to replicate this issue.

Comment: @SebastianBochan Thx for replying, I'm using the latest chrome as well, and it is replicating. I've tried `spacingRight` but it doesn't really work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use x and y offsets to align legend, to achieve your expected result following x offset value will fix the issue

```
legend:{
  align: "right",
  floating: true,
  verticalAlign: "middle",
  layout: "vertical",
  x:-3
}
```

Updated fiddle- https://jsfiddle.net/Nagasai_Aytha/aquurLfc/16/

Comment: @Feedfefat , i just used x: -3 but you can adjust according your requirement .. Hope this is helpful for you :)

Comment: Awesome answer! I've been thinking of some workarounds, but this seems to be the simplest way! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had a special case rendering many charts and had to use floating legends. My case was fairly complicated which also required the ability to print the reports and there was a lot of variable data to be rendered. In the end I killed the entire pagination feature by adding the below code snippet after rendering the chart. Keep in mind I did some css hacks as well to revise overflows etc. Anyone who just wants to kill that pagination feature, the below code works great.

```
$(".highcharts-legend g").attr("clip-path", "");
```